# How to delete a row in a dynamically generating grid view?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, cart

Hello Respected sirs,

I am generating a shopping cart like ordering system, in which i add/bind the productname, productprice, and productquantity from DataTable to GridView.

I have Added an ImageButton to the gridview only for deleting the selected row.

I also know that we can not delete a row from a dynamically generated grid view. so i placed a code in the ImageButton Click event that deletes the row from DataTable (Which is STATIC during the whole process) and again binds the Data With GridView.

Please note that i hv already once bind the data with gridview in my "BTN_ADD TO CART_Clicked".

Here is my code snippet,

```
protected void gvorderlist_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        DataRow row = dt.Rows[index];
        dt.Rows.Remove(row);
        gvorderlist.DataSource = dt;
        gvorderlist.DataBind();
    }
}
```

and ASP code is,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvorderlist" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
    onpageindexchanging="gvorderlist_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowcommand="gvorderlist_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cancel Order" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgbtnCancelOrder" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                     ImageUrl="~/images/cross.PNG" OnClientClick="Javascript: return confirm('Aap Chutiye hai');" CommandName="Delete"
                    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am getting an Error which says : The GridView 'gvorderlist' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled.

Any help will be appreciated...
Thank You

Comment: Once you bind DataTable to Datagridview, changes in datatable automatically reflects in datagridview. On button click event retrieve unique column value and delete that from datatable.

Comment: PrakashVishwakarma, are you trying to suggest me that i shouldnt bind the gridview again in the "delete button click event" ??

Comment: in the imagebutton click event, i retrieve the row index of which row i want to delete then i do the above mentioned code...so please guide me if there is any mistake

Comment: U're trying to delete a row from datagridview which is a wrong way. Better u delete that row from datatable. Since binding is already done. Changes in datatable will automatically reflect in gridview. Sorry fr the delayed reply. Was busy due to sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explains everything. You need todefine the event method for `OnRowDeleting` in markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvorderlist" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
    onpageindexchanging="gvorderlist_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowcommand="gvorderlist_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gvorderlist_RowDeleting">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cancel Order" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgbtnCancelOrder" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                     ImageUrl="~/images/cross.PNG" OnClientClick="Javascript: return confirm('Aap Chutiye hai');" CommandName="Delete"
                    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And add an empty method in the code:

```
protected void gvorderlist_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // No need to implement code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes for the GridView are case-sensitive, so change `onrowcommand` to `OnRowCommand` and see if that fires when you click the delete button.  If not, you'll need to define OnRowDeleting explicitly.  (Also change the capitalization of onpageindexingchange)

Answer (score 0):

Give `Command Name=`**`D`** instead of **Delete**. It searches for `Row_Deleting` event when `Command Name =`**`Delete`**.